# Laravel 5.3 DB Select with different database

Tags: sql, laravel-5

I have 3 databases defined in my app (legacy not my design!) and I want to use DB Select to run a raw SQL but not from the primary DB.

What is the syntax for telling

```
 DB::select('SELECT....
```

to use a particular predefined connection?

Comment: You can set up multiple database in the config file and use this
`DB::connection('foo')->select(...);`

Comment: I have done that and named one of the connections "common" and added "protected $connection = 'common';" at the top of the model but it seems to always want to select from the default DB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why the $connection declaration seems to be ignored is simple: with the Query Builder (DB class) you are actually not using the Eloquent ORM. If you want to use the Query Builder, you have to manually declare the connection if different from default, like this...

```
DB::connection('connection-name')
```

Remember that the Eloquent models are extensions of the Query Builder. For taking advance of the Eloquent model (and in your case of the $connection protected property) import the Eloquent Model with a use statement

```
use App\YourModel;
```

and build the query with the same methods that you'd use with the query builder.

Useful links to Laravel docs:

[Eloquent (check the "Database connection" section)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent)
/ [Database - Multiple database connections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#using-multiple-database-connections)